# Reading properties file using @Autowired Environment spring java Null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, autowired, properties-file

I need to read properties file based on the input passed using the spring framework in a maven project. My property files and application context are present under src/main/resources

I am trying to use the environment api to inject the properties file.

Code:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:GeoFilter.properties")
public class CountryGeoFilter {

    @Autowired
    public Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public GeoFilterStore getCountryGeoFilter(String country) throws 
CountryNotFoundException, IOException {

    GeoFilterStore countryFilterStore = new GeoFilterStore();

    String value = environment.getProperty(country);
    if (value == null) {
        throw CountryNotFoundException.getBuilder(country).build();
    }
    String[] seperateValues = value.split(":");

    countryFilterStore.setGameStore(isTrueValue(seperateValues[0]));

    countryFilterStore.setVideoStore(isTrueValue(seperateValues[1]));
    return countryFilterStore;
    }

    private boolean isTrueValue(String possibleTrueValue) {
        return !possibleTrueValue.equals("No") && 
        !possibleTrueValue.equals("N/A");
    }
}
```

But i keep getting null pointer exception at line "String value = environment.getProperty(country);"

My applicationContext.xml(src/main/resources)

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:GeoFilter.properties" />
</bean>
```

I have also set the contextparam in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am initiating and calling the function in the following manner

```
    CountryGeoFilter objGeo = new CountryGeoFilter();
    GeoFilterStore response = objGeo.getCountryGeoFilter(country);
    return response;
```

I am very new to spring and not sure where i am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I updated the initiating code to use context

```
    ApplicationContext context = new 
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CountryGeoFilter.class);
    CountryGeoFilter testGeoFilter = 
    context.getBean(CountryGeoFilter.class);
    testGeoFilter.getCountryGeoFilter(country);
```

Now i am getting the following exception

```
   Exception in thread "main" 
   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
   Error creating bean with name 'getCountryGeoFilter' defined in .. 
   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
   'getCountryGeoFilter' parameter 
   0; nested exception is 
   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
   qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at 
   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
   annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a basic working solution to this below. Essentially, remove @Bean on your `getCountryGeoFilter()` method, and change how you are invoking it. I've provided a sample invocation in an @RestController class.

Also, this configuration did not make use of any XML configurations.

#### TestClass.java

```
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    public String test (String property) {

        final String value = environment.getProperty(property);

        System.out.println("========> Property: " + value);
        // TODO: Something with the prop val

        return value;

    }

}
```

#### test.properties

```
prop1=prop_1_value
prop2=prop_2_value
```

#### TestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    private TestClass testClass;

    TestController(TestClass testClass) {
        this.testClass = testClass;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{propName}")
    public String test(@PathVariable String propName) {
        return testClass.test(propName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just had to remove the @Bean annotation. Thanks